# Limit a table's cell's values to two values?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a two-column table but I want all values in the first table to be either X or Y, and no other input should be allowed. How can I enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a validation rule.

[Restrict data input by using a validation rule](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/restrict-data-input-by-using-a-validation-rule-HA010341586.aspx)

A Validation Rule on the column as follows will work.

```
="X" Or ="Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at

1. [Create a validation rule to validate data in a field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/access-help/create-a-validation-rule-to-validate-data-in-a-field-HA010096312.aspx)
2. [Validation rules](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/access-help/validation-rules-HA010285532.aspx)